# Can I use validation annotations (e.g. Spring, JPA, or custom annotations) for verification logic in Corda contracts?

Tags: corda

I would like to add validation annotations to my states to avoid boilerplate when verifying Corda transactions. For example, I might want to annotate my state with an annotation that prevents states from being created with negative amounts:

```
class MyState(@Min(0) val amount: Int): ContractState {
    override val participants = listOf<AbstractParty>()
}
```

I would then like to check these annotations during contract verification, and throw an exception if any of the annotations are violated.

Does Corda support the use of existing validation annotation libraries within contract validation? Can I provide my own custom validation annotations?

Answer (score 0):

An annotations approach would make the code a lot clearer, especially in cases where the data model is very complex.

Right now you have two options of doing this

1. Embed the validator engine within your cordapp as a normal dependency, in which case you are providing an implementation to your members, who must trust you.
2. Individual members can attach their chosen validator engine to a transaction as a normal attachment, which will make the validator classes available on the classpath during the contract verify. In this scenario each counterparty to a transaction is responsible for checking the attachment hash is listed in a whitelist of validators they have previously audited.

However, we would like to warn you of some associated risks, which are listed below.

1. Determinism. In the future, Corda will run contracts inside a deterministic JVM (DJVM), where any non-deterministic code would fail to execute. It is possible some of the available JSR303 validator implementations rely on non-deterministic code. It is important to emphasise, that contracts which do work now, might stop working in the future, once DJVM is fully implemented. R3 intends to provide a Gradle plugin, which would verify code for determinism during the build time, which would help developers to eliminate all non-deterministic libraries from their contracts.
2. Some JSR303 implementations, such as the one from Hibernate, are very heavy (about 120k lines of code). In the future, contract classes will be loaded by a transaction scoped classloader, i.e. classes will be reloaded from a scratch for verification of each transaction. Given that hibernate validator takes about 20-30 seconds to self-initialise, it will become a performance bottleneck. There might be a need to write a custom implementation of the JSR re-using Hibernate's validator logic but stripping out the more advanced features that are irrelevant in contract context.
3. As a general recommendation, we encourage you to consider moving some of the heavy lifting to flows, as they don't have any DJVM-related restrictions.
4. If annotations are used, Corda will still require some forms of validation that aren’t provided by any JSR303 annotations, eg transaction level validations such as matching signers vs participants etc. Hence, some Contract code will still have to be written.
5. You will have to provide a mechanism for your members to audit and validate the chosen validation implementation. As this will now form part of the contract to which they are a signing party. It is worth discussion around the situation if a validator is found to be faulty in the future.

We really like the idea of using JSR303 annotations for data model validation and we will help you through the journey to implement it, so if you encounter any issues let us know.